# python not reading file object past 137 bytes?

Tags: python, mat-file

I am retrieving a .mat file using python requests and trying to read it. I can read it fine using read() with an argument of up to 137, but if I try read(138) or higher, nothing prints and the script ends with no error message.

```
import requests
r = requests.get(requestURL,stream=True) 
print r.raw
print r.raw.read(137)
print 'done'
r.raw.close()
```

returns

```
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x106c6c350>
MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Sat Oct 22 06:30:22 2016                                       
done  
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

while the same exact code with read(138) instead of read(137) returns

```
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x109a88350>
[Finished in 2.1s]
```

As you can see, nothing prints (including 'done' which should print afterward), but no error is raised and the script seems to fully execute. I'm thinking this may have something to do with how .mat data is formatted (since I can't print any of the data), but I don't really know anything about that. I'm mostly just confused why this happens...

Comment: Try `print repr(r.raw.read(138))`

Comment: Shot in the dark here: try `import sys` then at the end of your scrip put `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Comment: If it's binary data, there might be a `null` byte in it screwing with STDOUT.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, `repr` worked but not `sys.stdout.flush()`. It ended up printing some stuff with lots of x's and backslashes.